# Simple code to expire Drupal cookie?

Tags: drupal, cookies

With a single click this simple script will do a multi-logout of:

Moodle

Elgg

2 MyBB's and

(not) Drupal.

```
    <?php
setcookie( 'Elgg', '', -3600, '/', '.domain.com', false, false);
setcookie( 'http_auth_ext_complete', '1', -3600, '/d/', '.domain.com', false, false);
// setcookie( 'http_auth_ext_complete', '1', -3600, '/d/', 'domain.com', false, false); 
setcookie( 'mybbuser', '', -3600, '/', '.domain.com', false, false);
setcookie( 'mybbuser', '', -3600, '/bb/', '.domain.com', false, false);

   // unset all 3 Moodle cookies, the lazy way
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
        $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
        foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
            $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
            $name = trim($parts[0]);
            setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
            setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
        }
    }

    ?>
```

This works on four sites but the Drupal cookie won't quit. How can I do the same with Drupal?

Note: Drupal uses 'host' instead of 'domain', neither with or without the '.' works so far.

Thank you.

EDIT: 
I'm sure the cookie twice had *"Host  domain.com"* and on another login used the more standard format *"Domain  .domain.com"*

The cookie named "http_auth_ext_complete" **is getting expired** and I am still logged in. Drupal uses a second cookie with the session ID as the cookie name + there is a matching entry in the session database table, also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the session cookie used by Drupal is not constant, but constructed based on an MD5 hash of the cookie domain of the specific Drupal installation - see [`conf_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/conf_init/6) in 'bootstrap.inc' for details (hashing occurs on the last line of the function).

This session cookie is the one you'd need to get rid of in order to enforce a log out. If your script is supposed to work for a specific Drupal instance only, you could adjust it to use the specific session cookie name (will break if the cookie domain changes). If it is intended for a more general use, you'd need to come up with a dynamic version that mimics the way Drupal generates the name, i.e. 'SESS' . md5([cookie_domain]), with some complications in case of SSL.

Comment: Henrik,
You helped a lot since I didn't notice this... SESSba531e5bb92e887209d374287940xxxx...
 was the exact same cookie name on each login. Thank you very much.  :)

"Vote Up requires 15 reputation" (Hopefully others will come through)